# Is it possible to get byte identical compressed files with Zlib in Python and Ionic.Zlib in c#?

Tags: c#, python, compression, zlib

I have an [uncompressed file](https://filebin.ca/4o1NsuSwr1mV/fileToCompress.txt) that has been compressed with **Zlib** in *Python* and would like to compress it with **Ionic.Zlib** in *c#* and get the exact same compressed output file as *Python*'s.

I was using `System.IO.compression` and `DeflateStream` at first, but the result was nowhere near identical. I am now using the **Ionic.Zlib** library for *c#* and getting closer to my goal, but some bytes are still different (or a lot of them, depending on the file.

This is the Python code:

```py
import zlib

def compress():
    with open("compressedFile.dat", "wb") as compressedFile:
        with open("fileToCompress.txt", "rb") as fileToCompress:
            data = fileToCompress.read()
        compressedData = zlib.compress(data, 9)
        compressedFile.write(compressedData)
```

and this is what I wrote in c# to try to get the same compressed output file:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Ionic.Zlib;

static class myClass{
    static void compress(){
        BinaryWriter compressedFile = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("compressedFile.dat", FileMode.Create));
        var compressedData = Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream.CompressBuffer(File.ReadAllBytes("fileToCompress.txt"));
        compressedFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        compressedFile.Write(compressedData);
    }

    static void Main(){
        compress();
    }
}
```

Compression level is the same (`9`) and the compression header (first 2 bytes) are identical in both compressed files (`78 DA`). Next 3 bytes seem to be identical as well (`EC 7D 0B`) and then the rest really depends on the input uncompressed file... [The first one](https://filebin.ca/4o1NsuSwr1mV/fileToCompress.txt) I am trying to compress only has 2 bytes that are different among the 4 last bytes: `**6E A5** 55 53` (*Python*) vs `**6C 02** 55 53` (*c#*).

Thank you!

**EDIT: *SOLVED***
For anyone who would like to know how to get the exact same compression as Python's `Zlib.compress` in c#, use **[zlibnet](https://github.com/gdalsnes/zlibnet)**.

Get zlibnet.dll from one of zlibnet's [releases](https://github.com/gdalsnes/zlibnet/releases) and use `ZLibNet.ZLibStream(<output stream>, CompressionMode.Compress, CompressionLevel.Level9)` change the CompressionLevel.**Level9** to the one used in Python.

Example:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using(var compressor = new ZLibNet.ZLibStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, CompressionLevel.Level9)){
    fileStream.CopyTo(compressor);
    compressor.Close();
}
```

You need only write `memoryStream` to a file now.

Comment: `and get the exact same compressed output file as Python's.` Why do you care? If the zip file is valid and decompresses to the same result - what does it matter?

Comment: Compressed file just needs to be byte identical, for hash sum verification (pre-decompression and post-compression) amongst other things. Would also like to know the reason why the "same" function with the "same" library produces different outputs from one language to another (especially with the same compression level). But I understand your concern about the "why does it matter", though the decompression part does not matter to me at the moment.

Comment: Could you instead generate the hash based on the original (rather than compressed) files?

Comment: `Would also like to know the reason why the "same" function with the "same" library produces different outputs from one language to another (especially with the same compression level).` The short answer is likely to be 'because there is nothing that says it can't' (i.e. there are multiple byte combinations that will net the exact same decompressed output). That line of questioning is unlikely to help you with your problem though - unless you shift your hashing to be based on the uncompressed files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who would like to know how to get the exact same compression as Python's `Zlib.compress` in c#, use **[zlibnet](https://github.com/gdalsnes/zlibnet)**.

Get zlibnet.dll from one of zlibnet's [releases](https://github.com/gdalsnes/zlibnet/releases) and use `ZLibNet.ZLibStream(<output stream>, CompressionMode.Compress, CompressionLevel.Level9)` change the CompressionLevel.**Level9** to the one used in Python.

Example:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using(var compressor = new ZLibNet.ZLibStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, CompressionLevel.Level9)){
    fileStream.CopyTo(compressor);
    compressor.Close();
}
```

You need only write `memoryStream` to a file now.